# Synchronizing Database with server

Tags: android, database, database-design, data-structures

Is there any method by which I can set expiry time for a database(table)?

I have data coming from server on first time login which i store in database. The next time I need to have a flag or something associated with database which tells me its updated or not. Sort of Timestamp but associated with complete table instead of a particular row.

Comment: I edited your question for you. you can do that yourself next time someone asks for clarifications.

Comment: thanks for that. Any idea how do I go about it? I dont want every entry of table to be timestamped (by including a column). That would be too tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but if you need to keep track of when a table was last updated you could simply use another table `table_last_update` with two columns `table_name` and `last_update_time` or something like that.

But warning: you would have to update this reference table each time you insert/update the referenced tables. So this is *more* work (at runtime probably, and for the number of bugs this could introduce) than keeping a timestamp column in your table, and properly indexing it.

Edit: using a trigger on the referenced tables could be a nice way of implementing the updates to the timestamp table.

Comment: The problem with timestamp is I have exhaustive parts-details in the table and to check and update each entry will be quite more work. The idea of another table seems good. For the updation on change in the entry of this table can "TRIGGER EVENT" help??

Comment: yes, you could probably use a trigger to update the last_update table. hadn't thought about that :-)